# Css grid fr unit

Tags: css, css-grid

In Css grid i can make:

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
}
```

Is there any way to set widths of the specific elements.

For example:

```
.grid { display: grid}
```

and in the html:

```
<div class="grid">
<p class="fr-1>text1</p>
<p class="fr-2>text1</p>
<p class="fr-1>text1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, replace `1fr` with a specific width

Comment: I dont want specific widths, i want fr

Comment: you said `Is there any way to set widths of the specific elements.`

Comment: On the specific elements, not specific widths

Comment: The grid will only determine the layout position of the elements on the grid. You can still set width on element **in the grid** - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/OEYoGL

Answer (score 0):

This is more suitable for flexbox layout where you can use `flex-grow`

```css
.grid {
  display: flex
}

.fr-1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.fr-2 {
  flex-grow: 2;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <p class="fr-1">text1</p>
  <p class="fr-2">text1</p>
  <p class="fr-1">text1</p>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <p class="fr-1">text1</p>
  <p class="fr-1">text1</p>
  <p class="fr-2">text1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but i want with css grid.

Comment: @user2693928 I don't think it's possible with grid unless you use col start and end

Comment: If i mix display: inline-block, display: grid and display: flex the template will become gorgeous mess and hard to refactor. Css is disaster really

Comment: @user2693928 I gave a solution based on the information you gave :) I have no idea about you other code ... by the way, simply wait and you will get more answers ;)

Comment: Yes thanks, but i hate css - you have to mix 4 types of "display" to set width of 3 f*cking boxes. What the hell is this technology :) And on top of that if I refactor later i have to change other things as well. For three boxes, really :)

Comment: @user2693928 you don't have to mix, you simply need to correctly choose the right layout at the start ... you should be aware about the limitation of each one and use the best of them. In the other hand, there is no issue to combine display if it's well done.

Comment: I choose flexbox but then the grid becomes more complicated and i need css grid. But then css grid some other limitations and i punch myself in the head.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us what it is you are trying to achieve. At the moment this doesn't sound like an actual **grid** at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! This is how you do it. You're going to want to use the CSS minmax function.

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(100px, 1fr) minmax(200px, 2fr) minmax(100px,1fr);
}

<div class="grid">
   <p class="fr-1">text1</p>
   <p class="fr-2">text1</p>
   <p class="fr-1">text1</p>
</div>
```

and if you want to specifically assign those classes to that space on the grid you'll want to keep those class names on the p tags and then add this css to the above snippet.

```
.fr-1 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}
.fr-2 {
  grid-column: 2/3;
}
.fr-3 {
  grid-column: 3/4;
}
```

also, with css grid you can actually name your columns too which is really helpful especially when adding media queries. Here is how you do that below.

```
.grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: [name-start] minmax(100px, 1fr) [name-end name-two-start] minmax(200px, 2fr) [name-two-end name-three-start] minmax(100px,1fr) [name-three-end];
    }

.fr-1 {
  grid-column: name-start/name-end;
}
.fr-2 {
  grid-column: name-two-start/name-two-end;
}
.fr-3 {
  grid-column: name-three-start/name-three-end;
}
```

you can name this columns whatever you want. In this example I used; name-start, name-two-start, and so on.

hopefully this helps. Let me know if I misunderstood and I will try and help you solve your problem again.

Comment: It's not exacly correct but it works. In flexbox if i add another row it will be recalculated. In css grid i have to change all of the classes which makes me cry for poor css